# Can't get angular-carousel to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, carousel

I am using [angular-carousel](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel) to create a simple carousel. However, I cannot get it to work. Here's my [plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/yCPlX87otO2lLqGLamHB?p=preview) I am using version 1.3.15.

There are no errors but I just get a blank screen as in the plunker.

**JS(script.js):**

```
var app = angular.module('starterApp', ['angular-carousel']);
app.controller('tempCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}])
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="angular-carousel.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-app="starterApp">
    <div ng-controller="tempCtrl">
      <ul rn-carousel>
        <li>Map</li>
        <li>Cloud</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it working fine, but maybe the css is hidding the text on the `li` elements. You can add `rn-carousel-controls` to the `ul` element and will see the two arrows that let you move between the slides.

Comment: I am not applying any css. Everything is from the library.

Comment: I know. The CSS from the library is applying `position: absolute` and `width: 100%` placing your elements outside the view. You can uncheck this rules with the browser developers tools to see them.